# Scala - Get last two characters from string

Tags: string, scala

How would I return the last two characters of a string?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Scala allows you to do this in a much cleaner way than the standard `String` API by leveraging the collections API (for which there is an implicit conversion from a `java.lang.String` into an `IndexedSeq[Char]`):

```
str takeRight 2
```

The fantastic thing about the API of course, is that it preserves the type representation of the original "collection" (i.e. `String` in this case)!

Comment: +1 even if your string is 1 or 0 characters, you won't risk ```java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException``` when using substring with ```-2```.

Answer (score 22):

you can use

```
.takeRight(2)
```

---

```
var keyword="helloStackoverFlow"

println(keyword.takeRight(2)) // ow
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take (string length -1) that reveal last index of your string, (string length -2) will be next character from end:

`str(str.length-1)+str(str.length-1)`